# How to use the same UIPickerView for multiple times with different data ? - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uipickerview

I have one UIPickerView and one label inside expandable UITableViewCell and in the code I made 1 section and 3 cells all like first cell.

I did manage the data for every cell but my problem is when I select something from the first picker and I go to second picker and select something , my fist selection will be changed to same row order from the second picker .

To make it short how can I make the 3 pickers separate from each other and change every cell's label to the selected row from the same cell not else

This is a screenshot to my view :

[image: screenShot]

And this my code :

```
import UIKit

let cellID = "cell"

class callViewController: UITableViewController   {

var selectedIndexPath : NSIndexPath?
var tapped = false // when the first cell tapped it will be true
var flag = true

// These strings will be the data for the table view cells
let sections: [String] = ["Department:", "Team:", "Service:"]

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self


}

//number of sections
   override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int     {
    return 1
}
// header for the secation
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "Required Info:"
}

//number of rows in section
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}


//get the cell
  override   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! callCustomCell

 cell.titleLabel.text=self.sections[indexPath.row]

// now reload the appropriate pickerData

if indexPath.row == 0{
    cell.inputArrry=cell.departments

    cell.picker.reloadAllComponents()
}

else if indexPath.row == 1{
    cell.inputArrry=cell.teams

 cell.picker.reloadAllComponents()
}


else if indexPath.row == 2{
    cell.inputArrry=cell.services

    cell.picker.reloadAllComponents()
}


      if indexPath.row != 0{

            cell.userInteractionEnabled = tapped

            if (!tapped){
                cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()

            }
            else {
                cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
            }

      }

if indexPath.row==0{
    cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.userInteractionEnabled=true

}

return cell

}

// method to run when table view cell is tapped


   override  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

if indexPath.row == 0  && flag {
    flag = false
    tapped = true

   tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([

        NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0),
        NSIndexPath(forRow: 2, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

}

       let previousIndexPath = selectedIndexPath


    if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
        selectedIndexPath = nil

    }

    else {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath

    }

    var indexPaths : Array<NSIndexPath> = []



    if let previous = previousIndexPath {
        indexPaths += [previous]
    }

    if let current = selectedIndexPath {
        indexPaths += [current]

    }
   if indexPaths.count > 0 {
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
    }

}

  override  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    (cell as! callCustomCell).watchFrameChanges()
}

  override   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    (cell as! callCustomCell).ignoreFrameChanges()
}

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    for cell in tableView.visibleCells as! [callCustomCell] {
        cell.ignoreFrameChanges()
    }
}

   override  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
        return callCustomCell.expandedHeight
    } else {
        return callCustomCell.defaultHeight
    }


 }

}
```

Comment: I expect that you need to also save the state of each picker and reset the selected component when you call `cell.picker.reloadAllComponents()`

Comment: @Grimxn I may save what choice the user selected form each picker but what about the changing of selection in the picker if I changed the section of other pickers ? or can you tell me what state of picker do you mean .. like what beside the selection .. and Thank you

Comment: Try using this library it will show the picker for you with different modes strings, Dates and Time just give it the values you want to show and you have completion handlers to handle the user's choice : https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0

Answer (score 1):

Use tags in the attribute inspector tab in the storyboards and then make if statements to change what is returned

```
if (pickerView.tag == 0) {
    // Do something
} else if (pickerView.tag == 1 {
    // Do something 
} else {
    // Do something
}
```

You could even use a switch statement too.  Might look cleaner.